# Create Image Maps and store them using MVC3?

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-3, imagemap

So, here is the problem, I have a CMS that allows user to upload an image file that is supposed to be a map from a shopping center. In the same system, the user creates and uploads different information details about each store. The thing is I need to allow the user to input the coordinates of each store within the shopping center map by clicking over it, save them in database and render the map loading coordinates for each store.

Anyone has done anything similar or may be knows about an example I can take as my starting point? I've never worked with image maps, so any help would be apprecciated. I'm using MVC3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive done something like this in the past using MVC3 with the Razor viewengine.

The way I did it was to have two tables in my database, one for the image (stored image id, path to the image, and some other metadata that the user wanted) and the other for the coordinates. The coordinates table had a column that corresponded with the image id.

I queried the database for the image, and then queried the coordinates that matched the image id. Once I had this information, I would set the image source in the view, and load floating hyperlinks on top of the image at the coordinates that were in the database. These links contained an icon image, and when the user clicked them, a lightbox would open with details about that coordinate.

All you have to do is loop through your coordinates list in the view to generate the appropriate html.

here it is in action: http://www.merillat.com/inspiration-design/gallery-detail/hotspot/133/index.html

hope this helps